# html5 audio. How to get bitrate

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, html5-audio

I'm writing an extension for google chrome. And I have a situation: I've got a link for mp3 file, and I could play it. I could extract duration of it..

But how could I calculate bitrate? Is it possible through some properties? Or through some calculations using file size? If second - how to get filesize?

Thanks.

Comment: Any updates? I did some research and shared it, below.

Comment: I found only solution to make Ajax request with `HEAD` type and calculate bitrate after.. it's easy after you know filesize... But seems like it's awful solution. And of course it works with domain restrictions

Comment: Did you use the Content-Length header from the HEAD request? I updated my answer, below.

Comment: yep, it's exactly what i've used.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:**

Do a HEAD request and get the filesize from the [Content-Length header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). Since you know the duration, you can then calculate the bitrate.

**Research:**

Here I want to share some of my research.

You probably already know this -- the bitrate is stored inside according to [the MP3 format specification](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html). But I'm sure you would rather not read the file and deal with all that yourself! Hopefully you can find tools or API's to help. With that in mind...

- I looked around for public web APIs that will extract info for MP3's but didn't find anything that jumped out at me.
- If you can find a version of [ExifTool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool) that you can access from Chrome, it has an API to calculate bitrate.
- There is a Javascript library called [SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/) that looked promising, but it does not accurately calculate bitrate.
- I looked at the [Web Audio API](http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/index.html) but did not see any mention of reading MP3 files in particular, and therefore no way to extract bitrate.

Comment: I've been looking everywhere to find the answer to a very similar question to this. I'm hoping to use JS/HTML5 to extract the mp3 audio information, like bitrate, samplerate, etc. Is there a way to just get all that information? I don't even need to read it, I just want to identify files uniquely.

Comment: why not use arrayBuffer to read byte data and get the info yourself